# Change signing key for all my published apps. Is it possible?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have read the [Docs](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423#reset) for a few times but I'm still confused with the following question.

I have a few applications, published in Play Market under one account. All apps are signed with **different** keys.

I have decided to share data between them (AccountManager, ContentProvider with "signature" permission). Now I want to reset release certificates for all my applications, so I can sign all my applications with **the same new key**.

Is it possible for me? What should I do to have my already-published applications signed with a new common key?

Please, do not respond with theories! I already have enough. 
Please share your precious experience with this kind of issue if you had one.

Comment: I have same issue, how did you arrived to change the signing key of publised app ?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to change signing certificate after publishing an app, or even after installing it.
It is enforced both by Google Play and also by each Android device.
So the ways you can share data between your apps is either by making the content provider public (very unsafe) or via a dedicated server endpoint that will serve both apps.

Another way is to republish your apps under a different package name, this time all with the same certificate, and also publish an update to the old apps that will show a "sorry, you'll need to replace this app with a new one" message to the users and give a link to the new app in Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

With my experience you have to create a new jks file and change the package name, when you publish the apk on google play store.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not my case. I need my apps to remain with the same package name

Comment: As i know, no way to do that.

Comment: otherwise, no way to do that